# state district json binding react

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to display display list of districts from the json, receiving the following error 
'TypeError: suggestion.districts.slice(...).toLowerCase is not a function'
json file.

How can I get the list of districts details, so that I can perform autocomplete using downshift?

any help appreciated.

json format

```
{  
    "states":[  
       {  
          "state":"Andhra Pradesh",
          "districts":[  
             "Anantapur",
             "Chittoor",
             "East Godavari",
          ]
       },
       {  
          "state":"Arunachal Pradesh",
          "districts":[  
             "Tawang",
             "West Kameng",
             "East Kameng",
           ]
       },
}
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import statedist from "./StateDistrict.json";

const suggestions = statedist.states;

/*.... */

function getSuggestions(value, { showEmpty = false } = {}) {
   // const StatesSelected=props.StatesSelected;
    const inputValue = deburr(value.trim()).toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;
    let count = 0;
//console.log(StatesSelected)
    return inputLength === 0 && !showEmpty
        ? []
        : suggestions.filter(suggestion => {
            const keep =
                count < 5 &&
                suggestion.districts.slice(0, inputLength).toLowerCase() === inputValue;

            if (keep) {
                count += 1;
            }

            return keep;
        });
}
function renderSuggestion(suggestionProps) {
    const {
        suggestion,
        index,
        itemProps,
        highlightedIndex,
        selectedItem
    } = suggestionProps;
    const isHighlighted = highlightedIndex === index;
    const isSelected = (selectedItem || "").indexOf(suggestion.districts) > -1;

    return (
        <MenuItem
            {...itemProps}
            key={suggestion.districts[0]}
            selected={isHighlighted}
            component="div"
            style={{
                fontWeight: isSelected ? 500 : 400
            }}
        >
            {suggestion.districts[0]} -- how can I get all the values instead of one here
        </MenuItem>
    );
}
class autoCompleteState extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            SelectedState:'',
        }
       // this.showProfile = this.showProfile.bind(this)
    }
    setSelectedDistrict = (newState) => {
        this.setState({ SelectedState: newState });
        console.log(newState)
        this.props.onDistrictSelected(newState);         
   }
    render() {
        const { classes, } = this.props;
        console.log(this.state.SelectedState)
        const StatesSelected=this.props.StateList;
        return (
            <div>
                <DownshiftMultiple 
                    classes={classes} 
                    setSelectedDistrict={this.setSelectedDistrict} 
                    StatesSelected={StatesSelected}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default withStyles(Styles)(autoCompleteState);
```

I want the district details to come as suggestion like state in the below image[image]

Comment: `suggest.districts.slice(...)` returns an array. `toLowerCase()` can only be called on a string. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are doing this:

```
suggestion.districts.slice(0, inputLength).toLowerCase() === inputValue;
```

This is throwing an error because `.slice` is copying `inputLength` items from your `districts` array and then trying to call `.toLowerCase()` on that array.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to filter your districts according to the `inputValue`. One way of doing this would be to use `reduce` on the districts array like this:

```
suggestion.districts.reduce((acc,curr)=>curr.substring(0,inputLength)===inputValue?[...acc,curr.substring(0,inputLength)]:acc, [])
```

If you only want the first 5 then you can slice the result of this:

```
suggestion.districts.reduce((acc,curr,index)=>index<5&&curr.substring(0,inputLength)===inputValue?[...acc,curr.substring(0,inputLength)]:acc, [])
```

Comment: what is arr here?

Comment: it was short for 'array', meaning the array you're operating on - have updated

Comment: can you tel me how can i get all the values line by line instead of one single line in 'renderSuggestion' method.. I'm receiving the district list like  "Anantapur         ChittoorEast Godavari", "TawangWest KamengEast Kameng",

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not overly familiar with downshift - you need to ask another question I think :-)

Comment: feel free to 'accept' this answer if it answered your first problem though ;-)